# One register call, two service workers after page reload

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I get some strange behavior when registering the serviceworker on my webpage and didn‘t find anything about this issue!

I use the serviceworker currently only for receiving/pushing web notifications via Firebase Cloud Messaging to the user. So when a logged-in user accepts to receive notifications (via a button), I go ahead with registering the service worker and after receiving the subscription object, I get the token which will be sent to the database.
As long as webpage isn‘t reloaded, everything seems normal. But as soon as it reloads, a second service worker is visible in dev tools (both are active and have same root source).
The only difference I can see is the part on the top of the service worker (their title?). On the first service worker it‘s just the basic web URL or localhost address (http://…5500/) and on the sw getting registered second and unknowingly it is basic URL/localhost + firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope (http://…5500/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope)

Maybe serviceworker must be registered in global scope in js-file, but I didn‘t find anything about that and only want to install sw after consent from user.

Another problem I ran into: when the user manually unregisters the service worker and tries to re-register it by pressing accept button again, de-bugging and error logging tells me there is no active service worker even though I wait until I receive subscription object back before getting token. I may think this error is somehow connected to the above, so it‘s not a second question but maybe additional information for the issue!

Comment: Just found out why I get two serviceworkers. I register one by myself and when retrieving the registration token for the user by calling getToken() (function imported from firebase messaging), getToken() registers a serviceworker itself as well. Now I just need to find out why it does that…